# Change position of SVG path

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to do a animation with dynamic values and I want to change the height and position of a path.

e.g.  I've decreased the height of gray bar changing the value v473.9 to v263.9  but want to keep the position of the element align to bottom.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/JoniEAHH/pen/vrWgXM)

```
<path id="SVGID_121_" d="
M213.8,74.6
l-8.2,6.5
l-43.8-15.6
c-3-1.7-7.8-1.7-10.8,0
L106.9,81
l-7.9-6.5
v263.9
h0
c0,1.1,0.8,2.2,2.2,3
l49.8,28.7
c3,1.7,7.8,1.7,10.8,0
l49.8-28.6
c1.5-0.9,2.3-2,2.2-3.2
h0
V74.6z"/>
```

Comment: add a transform and translate/scale the path to wherever you want it to go and whatever size you want it to have.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/IvanBisultanov/pen/wXPeQo
If this is something you are trying to achieve: I added `translateY 210px` on items that you are interested in.